# Storing SQL credentials correctly

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, class, class-library

First off, this is an educational question - not something I am implementing in a productional application since I am learning the basics of C#.

Currently I have a solution containing 2 (actually 3, but one is unit testing) projects;

- Form
- Class Library

Inside the Class Library I have a class called `Database.cs` and it communicates with a MySQL database. I don't directly communicate with this `Database.cs` class, but other classes inside the Class Library do (for example `Products.cs`).
Though, I need credentials to connect to this MySQL database and I am not sure which way to go to do it safely.

*Storing it inside the Class Library / hard-coding the credentials inside the class.*

This wouldn't make sense to me since a user can easily grab the DLL and he technically got the credentials to the database.

*Pass the credentials through the form to a class (like `Products.cs`) and that class passes it on while initializing the Database object*

Could work, tried and it works but I am not sure if this is the 'neatest' way to do it.

*Write a static class that contains properties with the credentials*

Again, if I create this static class inside the Class Library I am pretty much off the same as my first example. If I would create this static class inside the `Form`, I require to add a reference to the Form-project from my Class Library (not the way I want it to be).

I tried looking stuff up but I am apparently not doing it right. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders SQL is a tag too.

Comment: @bas: in this case, it's being used as an adjective. What kind of credentials? **SQL** credentials.

Comment: @bas: by that technique, "C#" was not being used as an adverb. "Storing" how? "_C#_ Storing"? Doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnSaunders that makes sense. convinced me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all never hard-code credentials into code because credentials tend to change over time so that means you will have to recompile and redeploy your application each time SQL credentials change.

Usually all information needed to connect to database is stored in application configuration file in a form of [connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx).

If your application is web application then you're good to go because web.config (a web application configuration file) is stored on a web server and is never served to web requests.
But if your application is windows forms application, then security considerations kick in meaning that any user who uses your app could peek into application configuration file and get credentials. If it would be Microsoft SQL I would advise to use Windows Authentication. But with MySQL I guess you're doomed to store user name and password into connection string. Then I would suggest securing your connection string by [encrypting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it.

Also if your users can/have to authenticate against MySQL server (enter MySQL username and password), then you could use a connection string template and substitute certain parts of it with user name and password:
*app.config*

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyApplication" connectionString="Location=myServerAddress;Data Source=myDataBase;User ID={0};Password={1};
Port=3306;Extended Properties=""""; />
  </connectionStrings>
```

*C# code*

```
var username = textboxUsername.Text;
var password = textboxPassword.Text;

var connectionString = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyApplication"].ConnectionString, username, password)
// at this point you have a connection string whitch could be passed to your Products class
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not hardcode your credentials as that may prove to cause issues, firstly if you need to change your login credentials to the database at a later stage then you will have to recompile your class library, secondly as you mention the security will be compromised.

It is a good technique to leave the connection information to the main application instead of storing them in your data layer. Refactor your data layer to accept the connection string during runtime, this value needs to be passed by the main application to the data access layer.

This way you get 2 advantages:

1. When you deploy your application, the deployed location can have a different connection credential than your development environment
2. You can encrypt connection strings in your configuration file so as to increase security